# How to resolve notice : Undefined offset: 3 in user_node_load()

Tags: nodes, users

I have moved my entire site and got this when I want to add content:

`Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in user_node_load() (line 3604 of /storage/content/39/170239/<mysite>.se/public_html/modules/user/user.module).`

Can it have to do with the fact that I have different users now on my site and that some nodes is connected to users that may not exists?
If that is the case, can I resolve this by editing my DB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess you might be right. I think I have a different version of the user module from you (different line numbers), but user_node_load() adds stuff back in from the users table.

If you are missing a user with uid 3, you will get this error.

You probably need to update all of the nodes authored by user 3 to another user, the following SQL should do the trick (replace {new_user_uid} by the uid of the user you want to move the nodes to):

```
UPDATE node SET uid = {new_user_uid} WHERE uid = 3;
```